# Passing --form data as part of ROBOT Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to pass the below API request in ROBOT framework:

```
curl --request POST --url <API End Point>  --form 'mldata={"id": “idname”, "author": “author name, "title": “title name, "description": “description details“, "version": "0.0.4", "image": “/path/to/image”, "icon": "base64 encoded image"};type=application/json' --header "Authorization: <Bearer Token>”
```

Written the same in ROBOT framework [Version: 3.2.2], but getting `error: "status=400, reason=Bad Request  body={"message":"Request is not a multipart request!"}"`**strong text**

It seems I am not passing the --form data in a right way. ***Request for help*** in passing the form data [**--form 'mldata={"id": “idname”, "author": “author name, "title": “title name, "description": “description details“, "version": "0.0.4", "image": “/path/to/image”, "icon": "base64 encoded image"};type=application/json'**] in robot framework.

How should I pass in the right way?

```
Onboard ML From External Repo
    [Arguments]    ${token}=default
    Create Session    session    ${host}
    ${data}=    Create Dictionary    id=${id}    author=${author}    title=${title}    description=${description}    version=${version}    image=${repo_path}
    ${form_data}=    Evaluate    {'mldata=': ${data}}
    ${header}=    Create Dictionary    Authorization=${token}
    ${response}=   Post Request    session    /v1/ml    data=${form_data}    headers=${header}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${response.status_code}    200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be send as a string , and also you don't need equal

```
${form_data}=    Evaluate    {'mldata=': str(${data}).replace("'",'"')}
```

As you observed , we have to pass this as

```
files=${form_data}
```

Comment: This time I am getting error: `Evaluating expression '{'mldata': "'"+{'id': 'idname', 'author': 'author name', 'title': 'title name', 'description': 'description details', 'version': '0.0.1', 'image': '/path/to/image', 'icon': 'base64 encoded image'}+"'"}' failed: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str`

Comment: Updated the answer could you try the new answer

Comment: I tried the update one, but back to the same old error: `status=400, reason=Bad Request 
 body={"message":"Request is not a multipart request!"}`. Also, the I checked the body from the response. It appears as: `body={"mldata": "{'id': 'idname', 'author': 'author name', 'title': 'title name', 'description': 'description details', 'version': '0.0.1', 'image': '/path/to/image', 'icon': 'base64 encoded image'}"}`. It seems it is not passed as form data.

Comment: Ideally it should appear as `'mldata={"id": “idname”, "author": “author name, "title": “title name, "description": “description details“, "version": "0.0.1", "image": “/path/to/image”, "icon": "base64 encoded image"}'`. Am I right?

Comment: Which robot framework library are you using for sending this request ?

Comment: Could you add that library also

Comment: I am using following libraries for this API testing: `RequestsLibrary; Collections;    JSONLibrary`

Comment: COuld you try the above mentioned formats and try

Comment: Tried both. But getting the same error: `status=400, reason=Bad Request 
 body={"message":"Request is not a multipart request!"} `. For the 1st:, the body in the response is `body={"mldata": [null, "{'id': 'idname', 'author': 'author name', 'title': 'title name', 'description': 'description details', 'version': '0.0.1', 'image': '/path/to/image', 'icon': 'base64 encoded image'}"]}`

Comment: For the 2nd, the body in the response is `body={"mldata": [null, {"id": “idname”, "author": “author name, "title": “title name, "description": “description details“, "version": "0.0.1", "image": “/path/to/image”, "icon": "base64 encoded image"}]}`

Comment: I tried another solution which I posted. It is working.

Comment: @iamstuck the own working is the first answer  mentioned  , what is the difference between the first one and the one you mentioned

Comment: For the first answer `Evaluate    {'mldata': "'"+${data}+"'"}`, there was a `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str`. Sorry, Did I missed any? I thought the one I provided was more explicit rather than defining the dictionary and storing it in a variable and then passing it to evaluate. But still not sure, is it better way of writing things.

Comment: This is the last answer

`${form_data}=    Evaluate    {'mldata': (None,str(${data}))}`

Comment: if I pass the dictionary contents inside the variable ${data} to evaluate step, it is throwing error status=400, reason=Bad Request body={"message":"Request is not a multipart request!"}. But indeed, this format of passing the contents helped me in framing the explicit contents without creating dictionary and assigning it to a variable and using it in evaluating step.

Comment: This one worked @PDHide. Also, in the post request keyword `Post Request    session    /v1/ml    **files**=${form_data}    headers=${header}`, `files` option should be used for multi-part form instead of `data`, else there will be error `{"message":"Request is not a multipart request!"} `.  This is defined in [https://robotframework-requests.netlify.app/doc/requestslibrary#Post%20Request]

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below code and it worked. There are two modifications I had done from the original post.

1. No dictionary is created, instead all the items are directly evaluated
2. Instead of 'data', passing 'files' in post request, as for multi-form request, files is required.

```
Onboard ML From External Repo
    [Arguments]    ${token}=default
    Create Session    mxesession    ${host}
    # ${data}=    Create Dictionary    id=${id}    author=${author}    title=${title}    description=${description}    version=${version}    image=${repo_path}    "icon": ${icon_image}
    ${form_data}=    Evaluate    {'mldata': (None,'{"id": "${id}", "author": "${author}", "title": "${title}", "description": "${description}", "version": "${version}", "image": "${repo_path}", "icon": "${icon_image}"}')}
    # ${form_data}=    Evaluate    {'mldata': "'"+${data}+"'"}
    # ${form_data}=    Evaluate    {'mldata': str(${data})}
    # ${form_data}=    Evaluate    {'mldata': (None,str(${data}))}
    # ${form_data}=    Evaluate    {'mldata': (None,${data})}
    ${header}=    Create Dictionary    Authorization=${token}
    ${response}=   Post Request    session    /v1/ml    files=${form_data}    headers=${header}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${response.status_code}    200
```

I am not sure is it the right way for passing multi-form data, but it worked in my case. If anyone has a better workable idea, please comment. It will be helpful for me to refine this code to a much better shape.

Updated the answer as per @PDHide comments.

```
Onboard ML From External Repo
    [Arguments]    ${token}=default
    Create Session    mxesession    ${host}
    ${data}=    Create Dictionary    id=${id}    author=${author}    title=${title}    description=${description}    version=${version}    image=${repo_path}    "icon": ${icon_image}
    ${form_data}=    Evaluate    {'mldata=': str(${data}).replace("'",'"')}
    ${header}=    Create Dictionary    Authorization=${token}
    ${response}=   Post Request    session    /v1/ml    files=${form_data}    headers=${header}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${response.status_code}    200
```

P.S. Thanks @PDHide for your support.

Answer (score 0):

This was what ended working for me. For anyone else with this issue

```
${data}=    Evaluate    {'username': (None, 'myusername'), 'password': (None, 'mypwd')}
${response}=  Post Request  ${Session_id}  ${AUTH_TOKEN_URL_PATH}  files=${data}
```